# How do i determinate if a sentence has digits/numbers, and then assign those numbers to variables?

Tags: c#

I already tried to determinate the digits in a sentence using 'isDigit', but this gives me a 'bool' output. I need an 'int' output.

What i want to do is, say, i have the sentence "cheese23"; "2" and "3" will be put in their own variable, so i can add/subtract/multiply/ etc them.
(x=2,y=3;)

help will be hugely appreciated (self-teaching beginner here)

Comment: What do you *think* you need to do?  Try something and we'd be happy to steer you in the correct direction.

Comment: sorry, but i dont know what i should "think" i need to do... C# is new to me, i'm just learning how to do stuff by googling it (that's how i found out about 'isDigit') and lots of try and error. I was just looking for help, sorry if i came too ignorant, but i will keep trying

Comment: no -- you **really** need to be able to sling some code.  If you can't even do that then you need to work from material such as tutorials and documentation instead.

Comment: I'm not sure what search engine you use for googling - Both Google - https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=c%23+get+number+string and Bing https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23%20get%20number%20string provide decent results...

Comment: @kirk im doing that actually, i just had a random idea and wanted to put it in action, just had no idea how.

Comment: @Alexei thanks, this helps (i was using the wrong wording and getting different answers as a result)

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
int[] intArray = "Cheese23".Where(Char.IsDigit).Select(c => int.Parse(c.ToString())).ToArray();
```

This extracts the numbers in the string in the order and creates an array out of it.
Then you can do `intArray[0]` to get 2 and `intArray[1]` to get 3.
Search up `LINQ` to see how those chain of methods did it.

Comment: thanks a lot, i understand this perfectly,but can i ask,  why did you put (c=> int......). I tried changing the position of >, but it gives me an error. why is that?

Comment: `.Where(Char.IsDigit)` is an `IEnumerable<char>` so `.Select(c => int.Parse(c.ToString()))` changes it to `IEnumerable<int>`.

Comment: `c => blabla` That is a lambda expression by the way. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx